# Insert record and map strings to fields?

Tags: python, sql, pymssql

Im brand new to python and SQL, but enjoying the learning curve.

I am making use of [pymssql](http://pymssql.sourceforge.net/ref_pymssql.php) and have what I imagine will be a fairly basic issue.

Within a function, I need to INSERT one record in a table, and pass into the INSERT statement some variables I calculated earlier.

Currently my code looks like this:

> `var 1 = "Hello"`
>   `var 2 = "Bye"`
>   `var 3 = "12/12/12`
>   `cursor.execute("INSERT
>   INTO table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)", var1, var2,
>   var3)`

This returns an error:

> execute() takes at most 2 positional arguments (4 given)

What am I doing wrong, and bearing in mind I am learning, what would be a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing in each argument separately to `execute()`, where it only takes two.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)",
               (var1, var2, var3))
```

Now, you are passing it two arguments. The first is a string, and the second is a *`tuple`* of your variables (notice the extra `()`).

Comment: Thanks.  If anyone has time, would love to see an answer using the newer advanced string formatting on my example.

Comment: Advanced string formatting doesn't apply here because you need to (separately) pass the query string and the variables. This is so the execute method can properly sanitize the vales of your variables for SQL.

Comment: Thanks Burhan.  So if (I am not) was restricted to using a future version of python where I believe string formatting will be deprecated, what would I do?

Comment: For the example you posted, you wouldn't change a thing because this isn't string formatting, this is telling the execute method to convert whatever is passed in as a properly escaped string in SQL. It is not string formatting despite the similar looking %s